# Access host node from within docker container

Tags: docker, networking

I'm setting up Gitlab instance. And setting up email notifications...

I have the email server postfix running on the host..

In the config gitlab.rb I can set the following email server settings

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "gitlab.simplycreate.online"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 25
```

As I can see the `smtp_address` needs a FQDN and not IP. The problem is Gitlab requires the container hostname set same as the main hosts hostname so I cant use it here!?
Is there a way to point it to the host address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your container with `--net=host` you can access to your host by `localhost`.

from version `20.10` you can run your container with `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` and access to your host by `host.docker.internal`